# Object in the SpaceManager Cocos2d is moving or not?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

how to detect that object in the space is currently **stable** or not and his position also.
which parameter gives us info about that or is there any function?

Answer (score 0):

If its position is constant through time, then it's stable. If not - it's not stable.

Comment: yes i know that but how to check that particular object is constant .. :-)

Comment: keep it's position in some variable. Each simulation step check if mySprite.position is equal to this variable (with some accuracy). If is equal - then position is constant. If you are using some physEngine possibly will be enough to check body's velocity is zero

Answer (score 0):

Just check for body's velocity and, eventually, acceleration. If you want to be super accurate in checking if your body is static use:

```
if cpveql(body->v,cpvzero)
   theyAreQualDoSomethingFunction();
```

However, as the documentation warns

> Be careful when comparing floating
>   point numbers!

So you might be better of checking if the absolute values of **body->v.x** and **body->v.y**  are smaller than some small precision value.

As mentioned earlier, to be super precise you should also check acceleration.